# Crate.io: Can't connect remotely

Tags: connection, remote-access, cratedb

I've installed a Crate DB on a Virtual Machine Ubuntu (xenial).
Since I want to connect to it from both my VM and my Windows host, I've tried to set the VM's IP on both params in crate.yml:

- network.host
- network.publish_host

The rest of the parameters I can see in crate.yml

But that won't do the trick (I get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error when I try to connect to "my_VMs_ip:4200" from my Windows host PC) and I can't find any way around it on crate.io nor on Google.

Would any of you have an idea?

Thanks a lot

NB: I'm running Crate 2.0.7

Comment: so, you can access crate from localhost? but not from your network?

Comment: Yes exactly! :)

Comment: please also post your config (incl auth config)

Comment: The result depends also on the mode your run your network adapter: Are you using the interfaces of your host (often called bridge mode) or do you map the ports from the host to the VM (often called NAT)?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm having the same problem, can't find how to connect remotely from my Windows machine. Where is the auth config file?